# How to pass the output of previous command to next as an argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, freebsd, pipe

I'm having a hard time figuring how to pass the output of one command to another as an argument.

Specificly, I want to pass the list the extended attributes of a file in FreeBSD, with [lsextattr](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rmextattr), and pass its output to [rmextattr](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rmextattr) to remove all the extended attributes. Yes, I need to do this because rmextattr don't have a recursive option...

I'm trying something like this without luck:

```
# lsextattr -q user some_file.txt | rmextattr user "$1" some_file.txt 
rmextattr: some_file.txt: failed: Attribute not found
```

I think lsextattr is working correctly, but can't pass its output to rmextattr correctly!!

```
# lsextattr -q user some_file.txt
DosStream.com.apple.lastuseddate#PS:$DATA   DosStream.AFP_AfpInfo:$DATA
```

Please, help......

Comment: There is probably answer on your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283097/reusing-output-from-last-command-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, `rmextattr` can only take one extended attribute at a time. So you will have to loop over the extended attributes that `lsextattr` returns and remove each one; something like this:

```
for attr in $(lsextattr -q user some_file.txt) ;do
    rmextattr user $attr some_file.txt
done
```

(untested - I don't have access to a FreeBSD system at the moment).

In response to the question in the comment:

```
for file in $(find ...) ;do
    for attr in $(lsextattr -q user $file) ;do
        rmextattr user $attr $file
    done
done
```

I don't know what your criteria are for the files you want to consider, but you can experiment with `find` until you get exactly the list you want and then plug the resulting command into the `$(find ...)` part of the outer loop.

Comment: YES! It works! Now, how can integrate this in a find command to check all files?

Comment: Excellet, worked perfectly, thank you very very much!!